# Remove QUOTES from - %(message)s

Tags: python, logging

This is the configuration sample:

```
logging.basicConfig(filename=LOG_FILE,
                            filemode='w',
                            format='{"Message":"%(message)s"}', 
                            datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',
                            level=logging.DEBUG)
```

All that I need is to remove quotes from **%(message)s** **(ONLY)** not from the whole configuration.

Not sure where to use:

```
.replace('"','')
```

**UPDATE**

```
logging.basicConfig(filename=LOG_FILE,
                            filemode='w',
                            format=LOGGING_FORMAT, 
                            datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',
                            level=logging.DEBUG)
logger = logging.getLogger('googleapiclient.discovery')
logger.addFilter(FilterNoQuotes())
```

Comment: `format='{"Message":%(message)s}`

Comment: @heemayl Sorry then for bad explanation, need to remove quotes from the content of the message

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Side note: if you're trying to log in JSON format, consider using a proper formatter for the task, e.g. [`python-json-logger`](https://github.com/madzak/python-json-logger).

#### Answer

You can introduce a custom [`Filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#filter-objects) that modifies the message part of each record's in place. Example:

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig(filename='my.log', filemode='w',
                    format='{"Message": "%(message)s"}',
                    datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',
                    level=logging.DEBUG)


class FilterNoQuotes(logging.Filter):

    def filter(self, record):
        record.msg = record.msg.replace('"', '')
        return record


root_logger = logging.getLogger()
root_logger.addFilter(FilterNoQuotes())
root_logger.info('hello " world')
```

will write

```
{"Message": "hello  world"}
```

in `my.log` file, without the quote in between.

Comment: messages still contains `"` but in the ones generated by google not by `logger.info("blabla")`

Comment: Then you are not attaching the filter to all loggers. Detect the root logger of the google library you're using, e.g. `google_logger = google_lib.get_root_logger()` and attach the filter the same way it is done with `logging`'s root logger.

Comment: I'm removing initial loggers: `for handler in logging.root.handlers[:]:
    logging.root.removeHandler(handler)`

Comment: Depending on the library, it may not be sufficient - some libs reattach own handlers if detect removal etc. It's hard to say what happens underneath without knowing the library you're using and probably a code example.

Comment: Please stop for a second and read your question again. The code I posted resolves the issue you have described so far. When you say "do not work", I can't reproduce it as the code works just fine. Revisit your question again and update it with a [mcve] that fails so I'm able to copy it and reproduce the failure on my machine.